# Better approach to set the data in kendo grid.

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Loading kendo grid is very slow.

I have a grid with 500-1000 records and 40 different columns.
The grid loads slowly. It takes few seconds(10-15) to load the grid.
Let's say the datasource is observable and is specified like this.

```
kendoDataSource = new kendo.data.Datasource({
    data: observableArray
})
```

what is the best way to update the records and show them on the UI.
Should I use?

```
observableArray.push.apply(observableArray, newData)
or
grid.kendoDataSource.data(observableArray)
or
define a newDataSource with newData and set it again
kendo.setDataSource(newDataSource)
```

Finally, how do I know whether the Grid is loaded completely? I have a busy indicator which spins up in the center of the grid and I want to hide the busy indicator after the grid is loaded.
What I do currently is

```
observableArray.push.apply(observableArray, newData)
//hide the busy indicator.
```

Since the grid is still loading in the background, after I hide the busy indicator, the grid is blank for a while or shows the previous data for a while.
The user thinks that the grid is loaded with empty screen. Few seconds later, all the records appear in the screen.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is the data method if only the data is changed. This will replace the entire data at once causing only one re-render.

The indicator can be hidden in the [dataBound](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/databound) event as this indicates that the Grid is rendered.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Stefan. I will take the approach of setting data using data() as the observable array doesn't seem to work as expected always.